# Timing Out using UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, vba, sql-update

```
Private Sub DTRTimeOutBTN_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DTRTimeOutBTN.Click
        con = New OleDbConnection(cs)
        con.Open()

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Worker_Attendance SET Time_Out = @TOut WHERE @TOut = null", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TOut", lblTime.Text.ToString)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        DTRTimeOutBTN.Enabled = False
        DTRTimeInBTN.Enabled = True
        con.Close()
    End Sub
```

Hi everyone, can anyone help me with this? When I click the timeout button it should store the current computer time based on the code, because the @TOut is a null. But when click the timeout button nothing store on the database.

Comment: `@Tout` will never be null because you are calling `ToString` on a string value which will never return null.  Plus, `@TNull =null` will never be true.  There's something else going on that is not related to your query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your timing out issue but for your query you need to use **IS NULL** to check if the value is null.

```
UPDATE Worker_Attendance 
SET Time_Out = @TOut 
WHERE Time_Out IS NULL
```

Comment: It's timing out now. but the problem is the whole Time_Out column is updating equal to the current time of the computer when i click the Time Out button.

Comment: Do you want to store a **new record** instead? Currently you are updating **all** records where the **Time_Out** column is **NULL** (at least is should be with my query above).

Comment: how can i prevent all records are updating in Time_Out column?

Comment: here is my code, i can't update time_out column




"UPDATE Worker_Attendance SET Time_Out = atTOut WHERE atTOut IS NULL"

Comment: Now that I look at it, shouldn't it be `WHERE Time_Out IS NULL` so it checks the field and not the parameter for NULL? I updated my answer. Why would you want to SET Time_Out to NULL when @TOut is NULL?